# Keyboard Focus not able to navigate with Link to a href on same page nextjs 13

Tags: hyperlink, next.js13, keyboard-focus

```
     <Link href="#main-content"> 

Go to main section </Link>
```

code for main section

```
<div id="main-content"> </div>
```

when using above code to create a skip to main section functionality, the focus of the screen moves to main-content but the current element stills remains Go to main section (Link tag) this becomes an accessibility issue. Is this a bug with next js 13 or there is another way to implement. for now I ended up not usine  and using plain  tag